# Dynamic Annotation change in java

Tags: java, reflection, playframework, annotations, hotswap

I have to change the annotation of a model class in java at runtime.
The scenario is on my web page I have a drop down when I change the value of drop down and click on apply button I have to put annotation on my model class based on the dropdown value.

For this I have used javaassit to put annotation on the class. I think the annotation is applied properly but I am not able to reload the class. I have tried to do it using HotswapAgent. But doesnt look like its working.

I am using play framework

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
ClassPool pool= Enhancer.newClassPool();
CtClass cc = pool.get("Test");
ClassFile cf = cc.getClassFile(); 
ConstPool cp = cf.getConstPool();
// Code for creating and adding annotation comes here.....
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(bos);
cf.write(os);
os.close(); 
ClassDefinition cd = new ClassDefinition(Test.class, bos.toByteArray()); 
HotswapAgent hh = new HotswapAgent();
hh.reload(cd);
```

Comment: You need to add code sample and be a bit more accurate with what you are trying to achieve. Also when you encounter errors it's a good idea to add the stack trace. The effort/details you can put in your question, the more likely you are to get a relevant answer.

Comment: ClassPool pool= Enhancer.newClassPool();<br> CtClass cc = pool.get("Test");<br> ClassFile cf = cc.getClassFile(); <br>ConstPool cp = cf.getConstPool();<br> // Code for creating and adding annotation comes here.....<br> ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); <br>DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(bos);<br> cf.write(os); <br>os.close(); ClassDefinition cd = new ClassDefinition(Test.class, bos.toByteArray()); <br>HotswapAgent hh = new HotswapAgent();<br> hh.reload(cd);

Comment: you cant expect anyone to put effort in answering and question if you don't yourself put effort into the question. Your code should be formatted as part of the question and you should state what you are trying to achieve and show any errors you might encounter.

Comment: Yah...actually I was not able to format it here. Also I am not getting any error as such. Good thing is now I am able to load the class and get the annotation working. Will put the changes made in code once I am able to format it.

Comment: If you found a solution to your own problem, post an answer for it so anyone who encounter the same issue can find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

please try this, you are able to load it if using the same class loader

https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params